# The cardinality of the power set with $N$ elements is equal to $2^N$

Tags: induction, problem-solving, proof-verification

Let $\mathcal{P}(X_N)$ be the power set of a set $X$ with $N$ elements.  I am trying to prove by induction that its cardinality $\mid \mathcal{P}(X_N) \mid = 2^N$.  Firstly, I think it helps to observe that this can pretty much be "rewritten" or rather fleshed out as

$$\mid \mathcal{P}(X_N) \mid = 2^N = 2^{N-1} \cdot 2^1 = 2 \cdot \mid \mathcal{P}(X_{N-1}) \mid.$$

See that if $N = 0$, $X$ is then the empty set $\emptyset$ and {$\emptyset$} is its only subset; thus, $\mathcal{P}(X_0)$ = $2^0 = 1$, which is correct.

(*) So assume $\mid \mathcal{P}(X_N) \mid$ does in fact equal $2^N$.  Then we see that

$$\mid \mathcal{P}(X_{N+1}) \mid = 2^{N+1} = 2^N \cdot 2^1 = 2 \mid \mathcal{P}(X_N) \mid,$$

which is true by (*), our inductive hypothesis.  **My question is (as you might expect if you have read any of my other posts)...is this a correct use of induction?** I apologize in advance if this is a tiresome sort of theme; considering my beginner's lack of competency and self-assuredness, competently-given feedback and assurance from insightful and encouraging users here is more than extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is "correct", but contains a massive omission.  Why should $|\mathcal{P}(X_{N+1})|$ be twice the size of $|\mathcal{P}(X_{N})|$?  That's the main part of the proof right there; everything else is the usual induction setup (which you did correctly).

The usual way to complete this gap is to take a set of size $N+1$, and distinguish some arbitrary element; let's paint it blue.  Subsets of this set either do or do not contain the blue element; there are $|\mathcal{P}(X_N)|$ of each type, which by induction equals $2^N$.  Hence we calculate $2^N+2^N=2^{N+1}$.

Comment: Oh goodness...I have a lot of work to do and sooo much to learn.  Thanks greatly for your (generous, clear, and concise) answer.